# Can't view color with Diffuse BSDF!

Tags: node-editor

I was following a tutorial on how to make realistic trees. In one part, the person makes a leaf and uses nodes to make a material. He uses a color ramp and the leaf turns black and white, but the person was able to view it in color when he clicked on  Diffuse BSDF. However, I still see it as black and white! I fear I have done something wrong and if I continue without trying to fix it, I will mess up my mesh later on.

I searched everywhere on Google, but I had no luck. 
Here is a screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

With the Image texture Add transparent and Diffuse BSDF with Mix Shader. With the Alpha of image texture connect to Factor of Mix shader as shown in image.

[image]

Another simple way just activate Image as plane addon in Blender. Press  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Mesh -> Image as plane. Navigate to the png image. Thats it Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to render view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the person might have enabled the 'Node Wrangler' add-on. Here's how you can activate it:[image: Activate node wrangler]
Then you can view real-time node updates like this : https://youtu.be/jIGJOwOjAtI?t=164

Answer (score 0):

You connected the image texture to a ColorRamp (black/White) and that's exactly what you get. if you want to see the color just connect the image texture to the Diffuse directly.

*maybe link the tutorial so we can see what is the issue exactly..*

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. I had to delete a material node and replace it with a material OUTPUT, thanks atek! [image]